# No Access to DHCP Server

Tags: switch, vlan, dhcp, fiber

Here's the scenario:

I replaced 2 core switches (3550 catalysts - 12G) on Wednesday. I have configured the VTP and added the VLANs to the database.

My core and ethernet switches can ping to the DHCP server. However, (most) of the end users are not receiving IP addresses. I have verified that the FastEthernet ports are correctly configured for the appropriate VLANs.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perhaps `no ip dhcp relay information check` is needed?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your DHCP server is on a different VLAN than your users, check that you have your ip helper correctly configured.  On the SVI (Vlan interface) of your user vlans you should have

```
ip helper-address a.b.c.d
```

where a.b.c.d is the IP address of your DHCP server

Comment: Thank you for the comment! My ip helper-address(es) are set up to route to the DHCP server, and I have confirmed they have the correct IP Address.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure *dhcp snooping* and *dhcp snooping trust* isn't interfering with the server answers. If the switch(es) are acting as the inter-vlan router, they also need to be handling dhcp relay duty -- which will add *giaddr* (gateway) to requests so the server knows how to answer.

Eg. from my lab switches:

```
ip dhcp snooping vlan ...
ip dhcp snooping
interface Port-channel1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan ...
 switchport mode trunk
 ip dhcp snooping trust
```

(upstream of this cisco is a nortel switch, then an hp switch, and the dhcp server)

Comment: Neither my core nor ethernet switches have dhcp snooping/trust enabled.